# Retrieving data from list for specific user input - Unable to print values

Tags: python, list

Ok, I asumed that it was going to be clear, but I will explain further in order to let you know what I am doing.

I created a list and appended specific information from another one based on a year input, the input is a year in format YYYY, so I tried with 1959 and it appeded all data for that year from all_rows to year_and_lifeExpectancy_list

year_and_lifeExpectancy_list.append([x for x in all_rows if index in x[2]]) # This appends information from list all_rows to year_and_lifeExpentancy_list, based on index input

Here I am trying to assign with a loop values from list position, just FYI I also tried with country_name_2 = year_and_lifeExpectancy_list[0] for example:

```
for x in year_and_lifeExpectancy_list:
    country_name_2 = x[0]
    max_years = max(x[3])
    min_years = min(x[3])
            
print(f'The max life expectancy was in {country_name_2} with {max_years}')
print(f'The min life expectancy was in {country_name_2} with {min_years}')
```

Output of this contains how the list year_and_lifeExpectancy_list looks, it has country in position 0, a code in position 1, the year in position 2 and expectancy year in position 3.

In part of the code shown I am trying to assign information from each position and also calculating the max and min values from position 3 and from a specific location based on the year itself (user input) and trying to print that information as formated in print statement...

The max life expectancy was in ['Afghanistan', 'AFG', '1959', '31.925'] with DZA
The min life expectancy was in ['Afghanistan', 'AFG', '1959', '31.925'] with 1959

I can't see the error, do you have a clue?, I am beginer

Comment: Can we see the first several items in `year_and_lifeExpectancy_list`

Comment: Your question should include a [mcve] with sample input and your _expected_ output, as well as a description of what's wrong with your current output so that we can run the code and reproduce the problem. We have no way of knowing, from what you've posted, that there even is anything wrong, let alone what it might be

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips on debugging your code. In particular, I suggest adding `print(x)`, `print(max_years)` and `print(min_years)` inside the for loop. Does this give you any insight into what you did wrong in your current code? Think about what you expect `max_years = max(x[3])` to do. Then look closely at what it actually does. Does your expectation match reality?

Comment: On a side note, a list is intended to store a sequence of similar data. In your case, you are using a list to store a sequence of related data, but each entry represents something different (country name, abbreviation, year, and life expectancy). This data would be better represented in a dictionary or a class so that you can give each of these proper names rather than just using a numerical index. If you haven't learned about dictionaries and classes yet, I suggest you take a look at them when you have some time in your python studies. Good luck!